# Too many YGC in short period of time?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

We are monitoring the gc and below is snapshot

```
  Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P   YGC     YGCT       FGC    FGCT     GCT
      1118019.5  78.57   0.00  81.28  95.76  80.30  13078  708.590   107   16.394  724.984
      1118024.6  78.57   0.00  81.81  95.76  80.30  13078  708.590   107   16.394  724.984
      1118029.6   0.00  71.43   0.43  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118034.5   0.00  71.43   0.96  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118039.5   0.00  71.43   2.00  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118044.6   0.00  71.43   2.53  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118049.6   0.00  71.43  24.05  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118054.5   0.00  71.43  24.69  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
      1118059.6   0.00  71.43  25.21  95.89  80.30  13079  708.592   107   16.394  724.986
```

Below we run the gccause to find out.

```
 Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
      1117986.5  78.57   0.00   0.32  95.76  80.30  13078  708.590   107   16.394  724.984 Allocation Failure   No GC
      1117991.6  78.57   0.00   0.85  95.76  80.30  13078  708.590   107   16.394  724.984 Allocation Failure   No GC
      1117996.6  78.57   0.00  22.27  95.76  80.30  13078  708.590   107   16.394  724.984 Allocation Failure   No GC
```

Is this any alarming situation? Just would like to confirm is this an alarming situation? What does it mean by Allocation Failure and No GC?

Comment: your program alloc a data bigger than eden, thus, which cause jvm gc eden.

Comment: What can I do? How to indicate of any memory issue here?

Comment: Are you seeing any actual issues with the running of your program (like long pauses)?

Comment: @SimonC if your program really need as much as that, just enlarge -Xms1g - Xmx2g

Comment: The problem is my application is socket listener so I dont really know how to judge on the pause? What could be the issue here?

Comment: @farmer1992, GC tuning is a little bit more involved than just enlarging the heap.

Comment: @new14, what problems are you having in your application?

Comment: @SimonC i mean that if there are still unwanted gc after enlarge, there must be some mem-leak then check program. on another hand, that everything goes well after enlarge shows program really need as much mem as it applys, in this way, we should reduce the mem use of proram

Comment: @SimonC I do can see some little delay but quite minimal I can say. What my worry is why there are too many YGC is it that I need to tune some parameters?

Comment: @new14, that many YGCs is not alarming on it's own, but it all depends on what your application is doing.  If you don't expect a lot of objects to be created and have a short lifespan, then something is going wrong.  Also, the average young GC time is 50ms (708.59/13078).  Is this enough of a delay to be noticeable to you?  If not, I would suggest the delays you are noticing are elsewhere.  Have you tried running a profiler?  JVisualVM comes with a profiler built in, or there are more featured profilers like JProfiler.

Comment: @farmer1992, frequent GCs are not themsleves a direct indication of a memory leak.  Large amounts of old-gen memory not getting reclaimed after a full GC would imply memory leaks.

Comment: @SimonC the sad part I am tired of the visualvm linking remotely tried so many times it never work. So at last I have manage to take heap dump and now I am monitoring them via visualvm on another machine.I saw this java.lang.outofMemoryError 8 instance but the bigger instances are of of char =32367 and java.lang.String =28761. So what does this number indicte that this many characacter have been use or in use ?

Comment: @Simon Another thing I have also few lines to monitor the memory in the application itself. System.out.println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);. I notice after sometime there is a growth then also a drop too.

Comment: @new14, have you tried adding the following JVM start-up arguments:

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=31031 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

Replace port 31031 with a free port.  You can use these to connect JVisualVM remotely.

Comment: @new14, do you get an `OutOfMemoryError` in your application's JVM, or from JVisualVM when it tries to read in the heap dump?  If the former, can you include the stack trace?  If the latter, try running JVisualVM with a larger heap (e.g. `-Xmx2g`).

Comment: @Simon my application is running on linux platform. I have even set the policy file run the jstad and off the iptables. I have put the settings exactly like yours yet it did not manage to linked to my application and gave up after too much of time wasted on it.

Comment: @SimonC so far my app have not shown OutofMemorryError. Where I saw it is in the heap file which I made via this command ./jmap -dump:format=b,file=snapshot2.bin 1267. Then I bring to my pc and check it via visual vm.

Comment: @SimonC I used a lots of string variables and could be the way how I initialize or close them could be leading heavy usage of memory? I do use lots of resultset and statment but I do close both after using them.

Comment: @SimonC any updates from you based on my current explanation?

Comment: Honestly, this whole question says nothing besides "stuff is happening and I don't know what it means and if I should do something about it".  Your program runs fine and you're not leaking memory, what problem are you trying to fix? Numbers going up and down? The entire point of generational GC is to make eden GCs really really really cheap, at the cost of suboptimal memory use.

Comment: @millimoose I am seeing a small increase like 0.01 in the P when I run the -gc over few minutes? What does this say? I also got lots of variables declared a global variable so does each connection cause this to go up and I do call a number of 3 part libraries too?